# Send or Transform Multiple Type Parameters in query using spring

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, spring, mybatis

**NOTE:** I am using Spring framework + MS-SQL as database.

If I have a query for searching using two integers/Ids then I will do something like this

**mybatis.xml** - Query 1 -> **`Integer`** + **`Integer`** as parameters

```
<select id="listProctorLogs" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultMap="logResultMap">
    select SchoolId, ProctorId, DateLog, LogType, ImageRecognized from ProctorLog where
    SchoolId=#{schoolId} and ProctorId=#{proctorId}
</select>
```

**JAVA** - Java 1

```
HashMap<String, Integer> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
inputMap.put("proctorId", proctorId);
inputMap.put("schoolId", schoolId);
sqlSession.selectList("listProctorLogs", inputMap);
```

**BUT** What if I have one `Integer` and one `String` that I want to pass as query parameter, then how can I pass the parameters from **JAVA** and how I get them in **mybatis.xml** ?

**mybatis.xml** - Query 2 -> **`Integer`** + **`String`** as parameters

```
<select id="listProctorLogs" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultMap="logResultMap">
    select SchoolId, ProctorId, DateLog, LogType, ImageRecognized from ProctorLog where
    SchoolName=#{schoolName} and ProctorId=#{proctorId}
</select>
```

**JAVA** - JAVA 2

```
// What should I put here ?? HashMap<String,String> 
// or HashMap<String,Object> ... and how can I get 
// these parameters in mybatis.xml if parameters are either
// String or Object (convert to Interger) ??
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `Map<String, Object>` version.

```
Map<String, Object> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
inputMap.put("proctorId", proctorId);
inputMap.put("schoolName", schoolName);
sqlSession.selectList("listProctorLogs", inputMap);
```

But, this is just to let your code compile properly. At runtime, this generics information does not exist due to ***type erasure***. So, for MyBatis, it's no different than using a `Map<String, Integer>`, `Map<Object, Object>`, or even a non-generic `Map` itself because it's inspecting the parameters types at runtime and using an appropriate `TypeHandler` for you.

Comment: Can you please me a reference of documentation or article where it stated that " `Map<String, Integer>`, `Map<Object, Object>`, or even a non-generic `Map` itself because it's inspecting the parameters types at runtime and using an appropriate `TypeHandler` for you. ". Thanks